# Browsers cannot load my css file fully?

Tags: html, css

I have got a problem that when I preview my website in browser, loads part of my `.css`. Even if I update my `.css` file, the styles don't display. May anyone give me a suggestions?

[It was just loaded incompletely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkyHz.png)

[There is no ".journals-head > h1" in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4huja.png)

Actually I have ".journals-head > h1" following ".journals-head" in my css file.

Comment: It's being cached. You can manually refresh it by doing `CTRL + F5` in Chrome. Otherwise, in your `<link>`, change `myCss.css` to `myCss.css?1`. The browser sees this as a "new" file, and so it will refetch it instead of using the cached version.

Comment: `w` in line 934 in your .css file is the start of the something syntactically correct or it is the complete line?

Comment: @Santi  I have used `cmd + shift + R` on my Mac to refresh the css file, besides, I checked **Disable cache** on Chrome Network panel to disable browser cache. @MarianD  I have checked many times and there are no synctax error. @All people  It seems a vagrant bug, after appending `:mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=777"]` to `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/html",` in my Vagrantfile, the problem was solved. Thank you all, hope this helps.